# PHP distrubute files in folders with maximum X files per folder

Tags: php, file, directory

I'm writing function for cashing articles into .txt files.
I want to have maximum 1000 files in one folder and to access files simply by file name.
If ID of article is 5, it will load file 5.txt

Now, I have problem in making function that will find in what folder is exact file name.

So, in folder "1" are file 1.txt, 2.txt up to 999.txt
in folder "2. are 1000.txt to 1999.txt
etc..
in folder "10" are files 10000.txt to 10999.txt

Does anybody have idea how can I find in what directory is file name for exact ID.

```
function find_file($id){

//something here

}
```

When I call

```
find_file('1005');
```

it should return `2`

if I call

```
find_file('2305');
```

it should return `3`

Comment: `floor($id / 1000) + 1`? (@whoever upvoted this, where does it show research effort?)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
function find_file($id) {
    return intval($id / 1000) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Extract the number from the file
$filePart = explode(',', $fileName);
$fileInt = intval($filePart[0]);
// Divide to get folder name
$folderInt = floor($fileInt / 1000) + 1;
// Make it a string.
$folderName = "$folderInt;
```